# How to modify TCP congestion algorithm?

Tags: c, linux, tcp, linux-kernel

I am going to modify the TCP congestion algorithm (such as Vegas, Reno). I know this will need to modify the kernel of linux, but I do not know how to do it. If I want to change the RTT time of Vegas, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

TCP congestion implementations are pluggable, and are implemented in files in the `net/ipv4` directory. For example, the Vegas algorithm is implemented in [`net/ipv4/tcp_vegas.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/tcp_vegas.c). As the Reno algorithm is used as a default, it is implemented in [`net/ipv4/tcp_cong.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/tcp_cong.c).

You can modify the algorithms in these files, or add your own TCP congestion control algorithm by duplicating one of the existing files.

Comment: sorry, I still have some questions.Did you mean I should download those files into my linux and modify those files  into linux kernel? Thank you so much

Comment: @Nick I know this is an old question but if you don't know how to build your own Linux kernel, you should start with that before trying to modify the TCP congestion algoritm of your system. Once you've figured out how to build kernel module, you can use `modprobe` or `insmod` to load it. And to switch the active algorithm, simply cat its name to virtual file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control`. And obviously you can modify, recompile, unload the old version of the kernel module, and load a new improved module which avoids having to reboot your system after every change.